# Java 7 intersection types: what exactly does the specification say?

Tags: java, types, java-7, intersection, jls

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.9

- For each Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n), let Ci be the most specific class or array type such that Ti <: Ci. Then there must be some Tk <: Ck such that Ck <: Ci for any i (1 ≤ i ≤ n), or a compile-time error occurs.
- For 1 ≤ j ≤ n, if Tj is a type variable, then let Tj' be an interface whose members are the same as the public members of Tj; otherwise, if Tj is an interface, then let Tj' be Tj.
- Then the intersection type has the same members as a class type (§8) with an empty body, direct superclass Ck and direct superinterfaces T1', ..., Tn', declared in the same package in which the intersection type appears.

I would have expected the following code to cause a compile-time error, but it doesn't:

```
public interface I1 {}
public interface J1 extends I1 {}
public interface J2 {}
public interface J3 extends J2 {}

class C implements J1, J3 {}

public class A<T extends J1 & J3> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A<C> a = new A<>();
    }

}
```

As far as I understand, the Ti <: Ci types are as follows:

- J1 <: I1
- J3 <: J2

Now, I would need to have a Tk <: Ck, where Ck <: C1  and Ck <: C2, but if Ck := C1, then I1 <: J2 is false, and if Ck := C2, then J2 <: I1 is false.

**What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to confuse `<:` and `<`. If you read the next section about subtyping, you will see that `<:` is valid for a class itself - in other words, for any type T, `T <: T` is true. This is as opposed to `<` which is used for strict subclassing (`T < T` is always false).

In your example:

- `T1 == C1 == J1`
- `T2 == C2 == J2`
- `Tk == Ck == C`

and you can verify that `C <: J1` and `C <: J2`.

So it all looks fine.

Comment: Yes, right, I forgot that <: is reflexive. Could you perhaps help clarify the situation by giving an example of what would cause a compile-time error according to the quoted criteria?

Comment: I would have thought something like `A<T extends String & List>` would not compile (String is final and does not implement List) but it still compiles on jdk 8. So not sure actually...

Comment: @assylias I think this compiles because Object is the supertype of both String and List and there always exists a class Ck that's the subtype of Object